# In Print preview Dialog,after clicking the print button, the Print dialog doesn't show and page doesn't print

Tags: activereports

Program Language:C#
Component:ActiveReportsNET2
Version of ActiveReports:4.3.0.1261
Runtime version of ActiveReports :v1.1.4322

Other information:
1.the calling method:ActiveReports.Document.Print(true, false, false);
  the first parameter:Specifies whether or not the Print dialog should be shown
2.At one computer,it works well.But at another computer it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that two versions is different.
One:Platform target of application is set to Any CPU when compiling.This doesn't work.
Another:Platform target of application is set to x86 when compiling. This works well.

But I don't know the nature of the difference.Any way,I solved the the problem.If someone meets the same question,I hope it can help you.
If someone konws the nature,please tell me.Thanks.